# unable to execute execl() with MinGW on windows 8

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, mingw, dos

I have a file `hello.exe` file path is `D:\test\hello.exe`which is a simple hello world program (tested ok).

I have another program `proc.c` file path is `D:\test\proc.c` with code as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>

main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
int ret;
ret=execl("D:\\test\\hello.exe","D:\\test\\hello.exe");
if(ret==-1)
    printf("%d:\t%s",ret,errno);
}
```

The program hangs (windows dialog says `The program has stopped working`)!!!
I even tried `D:/test/hello.exe` as param to `execl()`, but the same...

Where am I going wrong???
Please someone provide me the right syntax? Please prvide me example codes using various functions of process.h with MinGW under windows. Web tutorial links are acceptable as well.

Thanks a lt !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include a library,

```
#include<unistd.h>
```

Because it is defined in this library So if you don't include this you will get AN error. 
and correct your code because you have written "exec" not execl.

```
int main()
{

execl("D:/test/hello","D:/test/hello",0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its all the same yet :(

Comment: Tried using `spawnl()` insted still doesn't work !!! May be MinGW has compatability issues with windows 8... Switching to MS Visual Studi Express 2012... Will keep you posted , Thanks.

Comment: the last 0 in execl() represents "(char *) 0" or NULL ,it is the last argument of execl().

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled with warnings, you'd notice that `errno` is an `int`, but you're trying to use it with `printf` as a string, which means it is being used as a pointer. Memory address 0xFFFFFFF2 (or whatever the  hexadecimal value of `errno` is) probably isn't valid.

Aside from that, you need to end your `execl` invocation with a `NULL` pointer. Otherwise the function will keep thinking it has more command line arguments, all of which are strings, until the first `NULL` it finds in memory or until the first invalid memory access, whichever comes first. Because copying the strings involves dereferencing a pointer, it will read the address made up of unknown bytes and attempt to dereference the pointer at that address repeatedly. If the pointer cannot be dereferenced, meaning accessing the address for reading data from it cannot be done, it will crash your program.

In the future, please compile with -Wall.

Comment: Thanks, for the updates... I couldn't find any proper tutorial on web for process management, so, refered W***pedia ("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(operating_system)") to implement. There the `errno` values for `execl()` are `E2BIG`,`EACCES`,`ENOENT`,`ENOMEM`. Which seemed to be strings...